# How to enforce the format of a string via attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have a data model that is a list of strings. This will be populated by user input but I need to ensure that the string they supply is ONLY of the format "**something:something**".

I.e. it must contain a **colon** followed by another set of characters (of minimum length 4). The current model (before requiring the colon appendage) was along the lines of:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error msg")]
   [MinLength(10)]
   public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
```

The only requirement of my old implementation was just a length requirement. I'm wondering what the best way to enforce this new format "**string:string**" is? I want to reject strings that don't contain a colon followed by 4 or more characters.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi @MichaelTruk, do you want ';' (semicolon) or ':' (colon) in your string?

Comment: @YongShun ah yeah how embarassing. I meant colon haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're validating the contents of the array now instead of just the array itself your simplest solution is a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<string> list = value as List<string>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            // not a string list, might want to handle this directly or just let it fall back to the other validators
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            var hasError = // your string validation here

            if (hasError) {
                return new ValidationResult("Your validation error description here");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Once you've finalized the detail of that validator the usage would be:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "some error msg")]
[MinLength(10)]
[MyCustomValidator]
public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
```

without knowing exactly what you're expecting, the best I can guess at for your actual string validation might be something like:

```
// declare this only once before the loop
var isValidStringRegex = new Regex("^\w+:\w{4,}$");

var hasError = !isValidStringRegex.IsMatch(item);
```

---

Also, not really an answer to your question, but see if [FluentValidation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) suits your project. Much easier to write tests for, and also easier to think with once you're used to it.

Comment: Do you think the simplest solution is to write a custom attribute class? Seems to me the problem could be solved with the existing [CustomValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=net-5.0) or [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @JohnWu, that's another good alternative for CustomValidationAttribute. I will add it in the solution. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @JohnWu I don't have an MVC project in front of me, but AFAIK the `RegularExpression` Attribute will only work on a `string` property, not on a `List<string>` or any other `IEnumerable<string>`. My answer currently has `string[]` instead of `List<string>` will fix that now.

Comment: ended up going with something similar to this! thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MichaelTruk want to accept it as the answer then? :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex, [this is information about regex in msnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)

in your case the string pattam is "\w+:(\w{4,})"

try it in [the regex online tool](https://www.regextester.com/), or console

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\w+:(\w{4,})");
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("string:string").ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Propose few alternatives. You may refer and apply it based on your requirement & suitability.

## Solution 1:

### Apply `IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext)`

You can write your validation logic in [IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate?view=netframework-4.8).

Prerequisites:

- The class must be implemented with the `IValidatableObject` interface.

```
public class Input : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error msg")]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (this.ListOfStrings == null || !this.ListOfStrings.Any())
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("ListOfStrings is required"));
            return results;
        }
            
        var regex = new Regex(@"^\w+:\w{4,}$");

        var hasUnmatched = this.ListOfStrings.Any(x => !regex.IsMatch(x));
        if (hasUnmatched)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("ListOfStrings contains invalid format string"));
            return results;
        }
            
        return results;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Credit to @Callum Morrisson's answer, *Solution 1 is only preferred when the validation logic is not needed to be applied in different class.*

[Sample data & result output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MCH6id)

---

## Solution 2:

### `CustomValidation` attribute with Helper method

Credit to @JohnWu's suggestion, [CustomValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=netframework-4.8) with Helper method is another alternative as well.

```
public class Input
{
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error msg")]
       [MinLength(10)]
       [CustomValidation(
            typeof(InputValidationHelper),
            "ValidateListOfStringsRegex",
            ErrorMessage = "ListOfStrings contains invalid format string")]
       public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; } 
}

public class InputValidationHelper
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidateListOfStringsRegex(List<string> listOfStrings)
    {
        if (listOfStrings == null || !listOfStrings.Any())
        {
            return new ValidationResult("ListOfStrings is required");
        }
        
        var regex = new Regex(@"^\w+:\w{4,}$");

        var hasUnmatched = listOfStrings.Any(x => !regex.IsMatch(x));
        if (hasUnmatched)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(null);
        }
        
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
*Solution 2 will be recommended as the validation logic can be reused in different classes' attribute(s) [Don't Repeat Yourself (D.R.Y)].*

Comment: You can/should use `nameof` to guard against typos and aid future refactoring:`[CustomValidation(typeof(InputValidationHelper), nameof(InputValidationHelper.ValidateListOfStringsRegex) /*,... */)]`

Comment: Not sure credit is due to me here, I personally wouldn't use either solution. Solution 1 clutters the model, making maintenance needlessly more difficult. Solution 2 is nicer but if you're making a new construct to solely support validation, why abstract it through a black-box?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0)  could do the job:

> ```
> public class CustomerMetaData
> {
>   
>    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
>    // characters. Use custom error.
>    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
>         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
>    public object FirstName;
>
>    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
>    // characters. Use standard error.
>    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
>    public object LastName;
> }
> ```

---

Please also note that you can also do your validation at any point e.g. as part of the controller's code, without any attributes.